# QProcess: Destroyed while process (Web Browser) is still running

Tags: qt, browser, kill-process, qprocess

Is it possible to close a window or tab in an external browser after starting it using a Qprocess?

I tried the following (for example):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "QProcess"
#include "QThread"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProcess process;
    process.start("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/Chrome.exe", QStringList() << "google.com");
    QThread::msleep(1000);
    process.kill();
    process.waitForFinished();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But the process is not closed.

So, Is it not possible or there is a workaround? thanks.

Comment: Calling kill() only makes sense on processes that are running, so that's not the problem. The problem is probably your instance of process going out of scope and therefore destroying the instance of QProcess. Try using `QProcess *process = new QProcess();`

Comment: Well, it did not work.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.  You might also want to try calling [`process.waitForFinished()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#waitForFinished) immediately after the `process.kill()` call.

Comment: I provided a minimal example and process.waitForFinished()  did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not the best solution but I here it is:

```
QProcess::execute("taskkill", QStringList() << "/IM" << "chrome.exe" << "/F");
```

It only works on windows system and closes all browser windows but that is the only solution I have reached and will use for now.